# How to park a domain cpanel

Tags: cpanel, whm

I have a website with a name I don't really like. How do I change it? I read online that this process is called "domain parking" but didn't really understand how it works. I have seen the option to add a parking domain in my cpanel but if I just input the name I want my domain to have it tells me:

"Could not determine the nameserver IP addresses for “[domain name I tried to input]”. Please make sure that the domain is registered with a valid domain registrar.
"

I have no idea what this means or what a "registrar" is. I googled extensively and I saw a lot of similar stuff but nothing clear enough like a tutorial and that's what I need a "click here, then click here.." kind of tutorial. I know little of servers, whm, cpanel and all that stuff. Just want to change the domain name :)

Comment: could you link to the website?  And do you mean you are hosting a website that has a unpleasant **url**?  Otherwise I'd suggest changing the title on the website pages but that probably isn't what you want.

Comment: The title is not what I'm after. Let's say I have a domain called domain2.com . I want to change that name (url displayed in browser) to domain1.com. My researched pointed me to this "park a domain" option but when I try to add a new parked domain through cpanel it gives me the error I pasted in my question. As the error suggests I want to make sure the domain is "registered with a valid domain registrar" but have no idea what that is or how to do it.

Comment: forget what I said about linking to website, but any additional resources would be helpful (maybe link to a tutorial that seemed similar but you didn't understand or a screenshot of the error you get) this sort of stuff isn't really up my alley but I wish you luck!